# Create and run an android project without a device or emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, project, device

I'm trying to create a new Eclipse Project where I can test android classes without having to start the emu or connect a device.

I imported the android libraries, but I can't get it to work... My project only contains one java file where I use an android class, I only want to start it as a simple java app.

The error I get is: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!"

My question is:  How can I create a simple java project (in eclipse) which uses android classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is: How can I create a simple java project (in eclipse) which uses android classes?

You can't.

There are no "android classes". Android is an operating system, not a class library. The real "Android classes" exist only in the operating system, either on an emulator or a device. The `android.jar` file is merely a set of stubs that allows the Java build tools to successfully compile Android applications.

If you have Java code that has no Android dependencies, you can build that in a regular Java project, perhaps creating a JAR file that your Android project then uses.

Comment: Thanks... so I have to convert any java project to an android project first to make use of any android class... alright.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to unit test classes within your Android app, then you should look at creating an Android test project.  See [Hello, Testing](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/helloandroid_test.html) for a step by step guide in setting this up.

Answer (score 2):

There is something of an android simulator for running applications natively on the development machine, but it's not considered to be anywhere near as robust or well maintained as the emulator, and generally used only for very narrow advanced tasks where the headache is necessary to enable running supplemental profiling tools.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can...

You must use robolectric see documentation [here](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/index.html)

Yo can find user-guide [here](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/user-guide.html)